# Draw edges between nodes based on similarity using NetworkX?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, graph, networkx, record-linkage

Here is my toy nodes dataframe:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'a': [55, 2123, -19.3, 9, -8], 
        'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'ad', 'kuku', 'lulu']
    })
```

I am building a Graph with the nodes (each row of the df is a node with id and attributes):

```py
    import networkx as nx
    G = nx.Graph()
    
    for i, attr in df.set_index('id').iterrows():
        G.add_node(i, **attr.to_dict())
```

Now I want to connect these nodes using nodes similarity (cosine or any other distance function).
Questions:

1. Can I do nodes similarity with mixed types and apply different distance metrics for each type?
2. If my node's attributes are all numbers, how can I calculate the similarity between any 2 nodes in my graph and draw an edge if similarity between node 1 and 2 is above some threshold alpha?

For question 2 consider my above df is:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({
            'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            'a': [55, 2123, -19.3, 9, -8], 
            'b': [21, -0.1, 0.003, 4, 2.1]
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `networkx` does not implement calculation of similarity, so that will have to be calculated outside networkx.

For question 1, given the mixed data types, I can recommend [recordlinkage](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/link_two_dataframes.html). Using this library you can implement a logic for what combination of numeric/string variables is considered 'similar'.

For question 2, if the data is all numeric, then using [sklearn's pairwise distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) is appropriate (as of version 1.0.2, it does not support string dtype, so for string variables `recordlinkage`/another string processing library or a custom pipeline is needed). Something along these lines:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "a": [55, 2123, -19.3, 9, -8],
        "b": ["aa", "bb", "ad", "kuku", "lulu"],
    }
)

dist_a = pairwise_distances(df[["a"]], metric="euclidean")

# form links if distance is lower than some threshold
ix_a, ix_b = np.where(dist_a < 70)

# add nodes
G = nx.Graph()
for source, target in zip(ix_a, ix_b):
    G.add_edge(source, target)
```

For handling multiple columns (and distances), one will need to integrate some logic on how to combine (and possible weigh/normalize) different distances.

Comment: What about the adjacency matrix ?

Comment: Adjacency matrix is formed by the links. So you can construct it manually, by modifying `dist_a` or extract it from the graph using `A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)`.